AWeber API - How can I get my account ID for use with the subscribers endpoint?
I can't find anywhere in the documentation that explains how to find my AWeber account ID to use in REST endpoints. (But, I can easily find the list ID just fine -- I'm NOT asking about the list ID)
Researching online, I've found that this has been a problem since 2012. I'm trying to throw this into Postman to verify it first. Once I know the endpoint URL is correct, then I plan to implement in a PHP or JavaScript code snippet in WordPress:
https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/{accountId}/lists/{listId}/subscribers

I'm logged into my user account: Can somebody explain step-by-step where I can find my AWeber user ID? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong -- I have read used, and understand the basic principles of REST API, but auth is whole other story.
Resources I Consulted to No Avail:

https://api.aweber.com/#tag/Subscribers/paths/~1accounts~1{accountId}~1lists~1{listId}~1subscribers/get
Aweber API - /subscribers endpoint not working
How i can get my aweber API credentials from aweber account?
Retrieve All User Lists using Aweber API
What are the Aweber API Variables $account_id and $list_id?


Did you try to use the accounts endpoint? https://api.aweber.com/#tag/Accounts/paths/~1accounts/get

Hadn't even thought of that! Just tried it and get the error: {"error":{"documentation_url":"https://api.aweber.com/#badrequest","message":"Error trying to decode a non urlencoded string. Found invalid characters in ","status":400,"type":"BadRequestError"}}

And how exactly did you make the request, that leads to this error?

Originally I didn't realize you have to create a separate account to use the API, but once I got that sorted, I still have the same error. I'm not sure specifically what you are asking, but I'll try my best to answr. I created a folder in Postman that has my username/password for basic auth. I created a new request that inherits that auth. Then I send GET https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts.
